# How to use threadPoolExecutor for async spring

Tags: spring, multithreading, spring-boot, asynchronous

I have a requirement to use same thread for multiple request in async spring.
Here is the code which i am using :

Here is the Executor configuration file

```
 @Configuration
    @EnableAsync
    public class ExecutorConfig {

       @Bean(name = "threadPoolExecutor")
        public Executor getAsyncExecutor() {
            ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
            executor.setCorePoolSize(7);
            executor.setMaxPoolSize(42);
            executor.setQueueCapacity(11);
            executor.setThreadNamePrefix("threadPoolExecutor-");
            executor.initialize();
            return executor;
        }
    }
```

Here is the service file

```
public interface QueueService {
                public void createQueue();
                public void sendData();
        }
```

Here is the Service Implementation

```
@Service
    public class QueueServiceImpl implements QueueService {

        @Override
        @Async("threadPoolExecutor")
        public void createQueue() {
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
        }

        @Override
        @Async("threadPoolExecutor")
        public void sendData() {
            // Need to use the same thread which created the queue
            // Thread.currentThread() should be same for both methods
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
        }
    }
```

Here is the controller class

```
@RestController
    public class Controller {

         @Autowired
         QueueService queueService; 

         @RequestMapping(value="/create", method = RequestMethod.GET)
         public void createQueue()
         {
             queueService.createQueue();
         }

         @RequestMapping(value="/send", method = RequestMethod.GET)
         public void sendDataToQueue()
         {
             queueService.sendData();
         }
    }
```

Here is the Spring boot main application

```
 @EnableAsync
    @SpringBootApplication
    public class Application {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
        }
    }
```

Please let me know how to use @Async in 2 separate request to do the job done by same thread.

Comment: You can't do this without additional customizing the pool. But for start you can use `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()`, it will create a single threaded executor, and you can pass tasks to it.

Comment: Actually my requirement is to spawn thread for each queue. I cant use single thread executor that kills the purpose. What is the Additional customisation u are talking about. If u could point any reference to me will be helpful. Thanks

Comment: Haven't found something, spent 3 hours implementing my own realization by seems like you need to affect the class proxy to add additional information about necessary methods execution.
But I can advise you to make a workaround, like pushing events to a queue and handle them via custom threadpool manually